# Largest possible angle formed by $(1,2)$, $(2,1)$ and vertex $(0,y)$ on the y-axis, given $y<3$

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

[image: picture]

I solved it using law of cosine, then differentiate, but it seems really lengthy, does anyone have a better approach? please tell me.
$$\theta=cos^{-1}(\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab})$$

Comment: +1 to your posting.  In evaluating your posting, I don't care whether your work is accurate or valid.  What is important to me is the care shown in presenting your work as well as the effort behind it.  Very nice use of a diagram, and nice reference to the Law of Cosines, which was also my first thought.  My only quibble with your posting was that although you made it clear that there was an upper bound on the value of $(y)$ [i.e. $y < 3$], you didn't explicitly specify whether $y$ could be negative or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle $\theta$ can be calculated by subtracting the angle of elevation to $B$ from the angle of elevation to $A$.

Recall that the angle of elevation of a line passing with a slope $m=\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$ is calculated by $\theta=\arctan m$.  Thus, $AC$ has an angle of elevation of $\arctan(2-y)$ and $BC$ has an angle of elevation of $\arctan\left(\frac{1-y}2\right)$.  Finding the difference allows us to use the subtraction angle formula for the arctangent function $$\arctan a-\arctan b=\arctan\left(\frac{a-b}{1+ab}\right).$$

Using the above, we have $$\theta=\arctan(2-y)-\arctan\left(\frac{1-y}2\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{3-y}{4-3y+y^2}\right).$$

To maximize $\theta$ as $y$ varies, we can find $y$ such that $\dfrac{d\theta}{dy}=0:$

$$\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{3-y}{4-3y+y^2}\right)\implies\frac{d\theta}{dy}=\frac{y^2-6y+5}{y^4-6y^3+18y^2-30y+25}$$ and it is trivial to see that $y=1$ satisfies zeroing the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if we have a circle with $A,B$ on it, a point $C$ on it views $AB$ at a constant angle.
we are looking for the smallest angle circle touching the y-axis, meaning it is tangent to it.
which is very clearly true when $C=(0,1)$ and thus the maximal angle is $45^o$